# Cakephp 1.2 Pagination

Tags: cakephp, pagination, cakephp-1.2

I need a custom query pagination in CakePHP 1.2.

I have a reviews model and on one set of pages, it paginates the reviews model one way, and on another set of pages it does it another way with a different custom query.  How do I overwrite paginate and paginateCount twice in the same model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO

I wouldn't do it in the same model.

I would have two different models with different overwrites depending on your requirements and use them in the paginate method accordingly.

Something like.

$this->paginate('Superreviews');

$this->paginate('Normalreviews');

Obviously in both model classes you would have:

var $name = 'Review';

HTH

Comment: So how would the paginate function look like for superreviews? If I do this->paginate('Superreviews') then how do i pass in the conditions, fields, etc.?

Comment: same way you would if used this->paginate('Review') no?

Comment: i was doing it custom like this:  $this->paginate = array
     (
      'conditions' => array
      (
       'Review.user_id' => $userReviewing
      ),

Comment: nm, stoopid me: that sets it up and then I do $allReviews = $this->paginate('Review'); so its all good! thx!

Comment: sounds good. Remember that the parameter being sent to the paginate method is just there to indicate which model should be used for the pagination. The var $name in the model will specify the table on which the model will work on. Thus the conditions which will be used to build the SQL query to filter the results from the databse can still use Review.user_id.

Comment: yeah in that case no need for model overwrites if just the conditions can handle your wanted behaviour :)